# Separately counting two exact string matches in data.table (and aggregating at the same time)

Tags: r, string, merge, count, data.table

I'm trying to count the occurrences of false and true in a dataset to determine if an event is a comment to a post or a comment to a comment in a Facebook dataset.

I would like to do this in `data.table` as I've noticed that this is often the fastest and most readable way to do this. The code below is code that I've tried, and it works. I would however like to do this operation in one line.

```
CEM_CtC <- aggregate_comments_data[event.is_comment_to_post =="false", .N, by = event.post.id]
CEM_CtP <- aggregate_comments_data[event.is_comment_to_post =="true", .N, by = event.post.id]
CEM_post_data <- merge(CEM_CtC, CEM_CtP, by = "event.post.id", all=T)
```

It is essential for the process that the outcome table is formatted like this

```
event.post.id CEM_CtC CEM_CtP
    382719578      50     100
    238947597      50     100
    934829234      50     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, since you don't have a reproducible example, but something like this will work:

```
dcast(aggregate_comments_data, event.post.id ~ event.is_comment_to_post, fun = length)
```

Comment: I think `DT[, .N, by=.(x,y)][, dcast(.SD, x ~ y)]` is equivalent to `dcast(DT, x ~ y, fun.aggregate = length)`..?

Comment: @Frank you're right. Can even omit `fun.aggregate` if data is non-trivial.